# Make position items on image

Tags: css

```css
.left-side {
  width: 705px;
  position: relative;
}

.stats-block-info:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20px;
  left: 175px;
}

.stats-block-info:nth-child(2) {
  top: 25px;
  right: -70px;
}

.stats-block-info:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 165px;
}

.stats-block-info:nth-child(4) {
  right: -35px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css">

<section class="py-3 stats-section">

  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <div class="left-side">
      <img src="https://sendeyo.com/up/d/4ab00b7cd0" alt="" class="xl:max-w-2xl" style="width: 705px">

      <div class="ml-6 stats-block">
        <div class="stats-blocks">
          <div class="stats-block-info text-center absolute w-1/5">
            <span class="record text-5xl">40+</span>
            <span class="record-description block text-xl font-bold">Completed projects</span>
          </div>

          <div class="stats-block-info text-center absolute w-1/5">
            <span class="record text-5xl">120+</span>
            <span class="record-description block text-xl font-bold">Partners</span>
          </div>

          <div class="stats-block-info text-center absolute w-1/5">
            <span class="record text-5xl">80+</span>
            <span class="record-description block text-xl font-bold">Happy clients</span>
          </div>

          <div class="stats-block-info text-center absolute w-1/5">
            <span class="record text-5xl">50+</span>
            <span class="record-description block text-xl font-bold">Creative vision</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="right-side w-4/5 flex lg:ml-auto xl:justify-center">
        <div class="lg:w-2/3 xl:w-1/2">
          <h2 class="text-5xl font-bold pb-5 leading-tight mt-12">Creative vision and digital experience</h2>
          <p>
            Suntem agenția care combină tehnologia şi creativitatea, în beneficiul afacerii tale! Într-o lume în care digitalul e de nelipsit pentru succesul unui proiect, Noi am adunat o echipă de specialiști entuziaști și un cadru perfect pentru rezultate vizibile.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I need to arrange the elements at every point in the picture. I did this, but at different resolutions they are shown in different ways, the elements are shifted, although at the same time the `width: 705px` is with the parent, as well a `position: relative`. How to make my picture with elements displayed correctly how in resolution > 1600?

Comment: Don't use `px` values to position your items, use `%` - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: @Paulie_D not working in my cause

Comment: Then please demo *that*. just saying "it's not working" is of little use.

Comment: @Paulie_D https://jsbin.com/wodunifoso/1/edit?html,css,output